# PowerShell Invoke-WMImethod on WinXp Issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, 7zip

I am running the below Invoke-WMImethod against remote machines to 7zip up a backup archive. On Win7 it works just fine, on WinXp it dies. I am guessing it dies on the -p$pass in my 7zip options.

```
$pass = Read-Host "Enter backup password"
$7zip = "cmd /c $backuploc\7za.exe a $backupname.7z -p$pass -mhe $backupfolder"
InVoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $7zip -ComputerName SVR1 -Credential $cred | Out-Null
```

Again this is working just fine on the Win7 boxes..why does this fail on XP? and is there a way to get the password option working. (without hard coding password, exclude WinRM also)

Comment: What is the exact error powershell gives you?

Comment: I don't get an error, the Invoke-WMImethod sends the command to the remote box without output of the failure. From the WMI call response I get a 0 (successful) for a return call and I also get a process ID.

Comment: What version of PS is on the XP machine? Also, why not use PSsession to start a process and zip files on the remote machine?

Comment: Due to constraints out side of my control using WinRM/PSremoting is not an option. (this would have made my life easier on a whole host of levels). PS version on the XP (which is none) is irrelevant in this scenario.